# how to change value of string i'm for-looping on Python3

Tags: python

I'm trying to implement Caesar's Cipher, which offsets any letter by a given key (e.g. if the key is 2, then 'a' becomes 'c').

Here's my code:

```
key = 2
code = "abc def hi"
code_splitted = code.split()
for word in code_splitted:
    for char in word:
        char = chr(ord(char) + key)
print (" ".join(code_splitted))
```

However the input is the same code "abc def hi". What's the problem?

Comment: Strings are immutable.  They can't be changed, only replaced.  Instead build a new list of encoded characters and then `join` them together

Comment: While there are several answers below, none seem to take into account what would happen if the character + key is outside of the alphabet range.  You need to wrap.

Comment: @joelgoldstick i understand my mistake, but what do you mean by wrap? is there a function that can help me?

Comment: chr(ord('z')+1) will give you a non alphabetic result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you run this and check `char` you will see that you have been updating that object, but not the one you initially reference.  You can create a temporary blank string and string the new key, adding that to a list.

The below maintains your code for the most part:

```
key = 2
code = "abc def hi"
newcode=[]
code_splitted = code.split()
for word in code_splitted:
    tempcode = ''
    for char in word:
        tempcode += chr(ord(char) + key)
    newcode.append(tempcode)
print (" ".join(newcode))
```

Comment: performance of the inner loop is not very good. string concatenation with `+=` should be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

The foreach loop in python provides a copy of the item it finds in the provided iterable. This means that when you change 'char' you aren't actually changing the data in your string. The following is probably what you want:

```
for i in range(len(code_splitted)):
    for j in range(len(code_splitted[i])):
        code_splitted[i][j] = code_splitted[i][:j] + chr(ord(code_splitted[i][j]) + key) + code_splitted[i][j+1:]
```

When you do it this way, all changes are made directly to the original array, rather than copies created within python.

Edit: forgot strings were immutable, fixed code.

Comment: The compiler gives me    File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
    code_splitted[i][j] = chr(ord(code_splitted[i][j]) + key)
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment

Comment: Sorry, forgot about string immutability, I don't usually use python. Fixed the code.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify the items, you're modifying copies / try to change immutable objects.

That said, the best way to do that is using 2 nested *generator comprehension* constructs:

```
key = 2
code = "abc def hi"
code_splitted = code.split()

code_splitted = ("".join(chr(ord(char) + key) for char in word) for word in code_splitted)
print (" ".join(code_splitted))
```

result:

```
cde fgh jk
```

note that no temporary list is created so it's much better performance-wise, and more pythonic (no indexes involved)

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done by replacing each word you encounter and appending it to a temp array `new_code` and print the answer

```
import string

key = 2
code = "abc def hi"

new_code = []
for alpha in code:
    if alpha.strip():
        replaced = chr(ord(alpha) + key)
        new_code.append(replaced)
    else:
        new_code.append(alpha)
print ''.join(new_code)

>>> cde fgh jk
```